# Filter array of objects from another array of objects

Tags: javascript

From the given array of objects how to filter the expected output

```
let a = [{name:'Hari',age:2},{name:'Chana',age:4},{name:'Like',age:5}]
let b = [{name:'Chana',age:14},{name:'Like',age:15}];
```

I tried this but not working;

```
let c =a.filter(elm => b.find(el => el.name === elm.name));
```

expected output is `[{name:'Hari',age:2}]`

Comment: You need to flip your condition, so `!b.find(...)`. But I wouldn't use `.find()` here as you're after a boolean, instead, you could use `!b.some(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change little modification inside code of filter and final code will be :

```js
let a = [{name:'Hari',age:2},{name:'Chana',age:4},{name:'Like',age:5}]
let b = [{name:'Chana',age:14},{name:'Like',age:15}];
    
let c = a.filter(elm => !b.find(el => el.name === elm.name));
console.log(c);
```

Result will be:

```
[ { name: 'Hari', age: 2 } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the result of `filter === 0`

```js
let a = [{name:'Hari',age:2},{name:'Chana',age:4},{name:'Like',age:5}]
let b = [{name:'Chana',age:14},{name:'Like',age:15}];

let c = a.filter(x => b.filter(y => y.name === x.name).length === 0);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Not that it really matters because the arrays are small in this example, but `b.filter()` needs to go through the entire array, by keeping `.find()` or using something like `.every()` or `.some()` instead (which all exit early), you can avoid looping the entire array if you find a matching name earlier on in `b`